# Cycle detected when computing layout of `RuntimeCall`

Tags: runtime, pallet-collective, pallet-democracy

My pallet is using the following frame pallets: Democracy, Utility & Collective.
The error I get is:

```rust
cycle used when elaborating drops for `<impl at /home/kazu/Polkadot/fair-squares/runtime/src/lib.rs:634:1: 652:10>::clone`  
    --> /home/kazu/Polkadot/fair-squares/runtime/src/lib.rs:634:1 
    635 | ||     pub struct Runtime  
    ...   ||  
    651 | ||         Utility: pallet_utility,  
    634 | // construct_runtime!(  
    652 | ||         Council: pallet_collective::<Instance1>,  
        | ||_________^
```

I have two instances of collective, but I'm using only Instance1 in this pallet.
The trait Config is as follows:

```rust
    type RuntimeCall: Parameter
                + Dispatchable<RuntimeOrigin = <Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeOrigin, PostInfo = PostDispatchInfo>  
                + GetDispatchInfo  
                + From<frame_system::Call<Self>>  
                + UnfilteredDispatchable<RuntimeOrigin = <Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeOrigin>  
                + IsSubType<Call<Self>>  
                + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeCall>;
```

I really can't figure out the problem with RuntimeCall definition. Any idea on how I can solve this error...PLEASE?

Kazunobu

Comment: Config is not there edit the question.

Comment: I can't edit the post for some reason... I keep getting:`An error occurred submitting the edit.`

Comment: Can you post what error are you facing?

Comment: cycle detected when computing layout of `RuntimeCall`

Comment: Once try with `Self:: RuntimeOrigin` instead of `<Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeOrigin`, I think it should work

Comment: It's not working , and is ambiguous as `Self::RuntimeOrigin` could derive from one of Collective Instances, or frame_system (RuntimeOrigin is not present in my pallet Config)

Comment: it is hard to  understand what's the issue with the current information it will be helpful if you can post you repo link

Comment: https://github.com/Fair-Squares/fair-squares/blob/optimize_9.40/pallets/voting/src/lib.rs

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148491/discussion-between-shubham-gupta-and-kazunobu-ndong).

Answer (score 0):

After several experimentations, It seems that adding both `pallet_democracy::Config` & `pallet_collective::Config` to the Config of one pallet (Tight pallet coupling) is the source of the problem. This is probably related to the change of types implemented in the Democracy pallet (It was not a problem up to polkadot-v0.9.40~...)
I think the solution is then to create two separate pallets:

- One to Create the whole Democracy governance process and output the necessary call
- One more to receive the `democracy_call` (as the call enacted at the end of collective), format it, and start the collective process.

I haven't seen many projects (actually I haven't seen any...) using both pallets the way we do, so I get that it was not an issue until now.
Any additionnal information is welcome.

Kazu